# react/semantic-ui: How to get a fullscreen segment

Tags: css, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I would like to build a layout like the homepage example of semantic-ui: http://semantic-ui.com/examples/homepage.html

The first vertical black segment has nearly full height. It is done by the `masthead` class, but I don't understand from where this class comes.

I'm using react, so this is my layout so far:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Segment vertical inverted>
                <p>Main</p>
            </Segment>
            <Segment vertical>
                <p>First</p>
            </Segment>
        </div>
    )
}
```

But with this the first segment doesn't have full height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on this [example](http://react.semantic-ui.com/layouts/homepage) with SUIR, [source](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/docs/app/Layouts/HomepageLayout.js) is also avialable. `masthead` class is defined in SUI example and isn't part of framework, these behaviour was implement with custom styling:

```
<Segment
  inverted
  textAlign='center'
  style={{ minHeight: 700, padding: '1em 0em' }}
  vertical
>
```